# Valgrind Invalid write of size 8 when modifying variable in vector

Tags: c++

I am trying to modify the value of a variable within a vector of 'Vertex' (a struct I made) but when I run valgrind I keep getting this error, Here is my code and the valgrind error:

```
struct Vertex {
    bool discovered = false;
    double distance = INFINITY;
    size_t prev;
    double xcor;
    double ycor;
};


int numV = 0;
cin >> numV;
Vertex temp;
vector<Vertex> vertices;
for (int i = 0; i < numV; ++i) {
    cin >> temp.xcor >> temp.ycor;
    vertices.push_back(temp);
}//for
vertices[0].distance = 0.0;


==32151== Invalid write of size 8
==32151==    at 0x401B7F: main (amongus.cpp:128)
==32151==  Address 0x8 is not stack'd, malloc'd or (recently) free'd
```

Comment: Hint: what was `numV`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This happens in case `numV` is zero or negative. In that case the `vertices` vector will be empty and trying to set `vertices[0].distance` accesses memory that was not allocated (there is no first element in the empty vector).

Answer (score 0):

Your code is not safe against `numV = 0`. `vertices[0]` may just not exist. Why you don't move this last line into the loop?